# Covert Virtual Directory to Application using ansible

Tags: iis, configuration, ansible, windows-server-2012

How can convert Virtual Directory to Application in ansible playbook

win_iis_virtualdirectory will only create a new virtual directory

And

Win_iis_webapplication will create a new application which is under site not under virtual directory.

I want to convert virtual directory to applications 
Power shell we can do by convertTo-webapplication

But how this can be done in ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current windows ansible modules you have 2 ways to do this.

You can use win_iis_virtualdirectory to remove the virtual directory, and then use the win_iis_webapplication to create an application over the same physical path.

Or,

You can use the powershell and the script module to run it on the remote machine and convert it that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in an intuitive way

- name: Add your app inside virtual dir
  win_iis_webapplication:
  application_pool: AppPoolName
  name: YourAppName
  site: YourSite/YourVirtualDir
  state: present
  physical_path: C:\physical\path